# error inflating android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Good evening, 
I'm developing on Eclipse Luna. Today i've updated the SDK to the latest version available and after the update all libraries get an error so i re-imported all of them in the workspace. All works fine but when i launch one of my application i get this error.

```
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2352)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2414)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1318)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6865)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    ... 10 more
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    ... 23 more
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field abc_text_cursor_mtrl_alpha of type I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$drawable; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$drawable' appears in /data/app/com.example.myapp-2/base.apk)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.<clinit>(TintManager.java:89)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getTintManager(TintTypedArray.java:192)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:62)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:249)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:191)
09-08 20:49:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(14066):    ... 26 more
```

In the onCreate of MainActivity (that extends AppCompatActivity):

```
toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

My layout (toolbar.xml) is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>


And activity_main is


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>   

    </LinearLayout>

   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>   

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

To fix this problem i tried following solutions:

1- Delete and re-import android-support-v7-library into workspace (build target is set on Android 6.0)

2- Clean it and build

3- Clean and build all the projects of workspace

4- Put "@style" before Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

5- Delete and re-import all projects and libraries in the workspace

6- Clean all workspace and restart Eclipse

Nothing seem to works because i get always this error. Please, anyone can help me to solve if? Before that i update the SDK and support-library this error doesn't appear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `abc_text_cursor_mtrl_alpha` is not being compiled into your projects R class for some reason. Are you using any proguard config that might be stripping the fields?

Comment: @Kane O'Riley: Nope, i'm not using Proguard. This is very strange. Is possible that is a problem related to Eclipse cache?

Comment: Perhaps, I haven't used Eclipse for a long time. I'd suggest migrating to Android Studio now that Eclipse is not recommended or officially supported.

Comment: I have the same problem. The only thing we have in common is that we're both using Android 6.0. That indicates that this is probably an OS version bug.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to give app style in you values/styles.xml like that:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

or

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: The exception is due to a missing field in the R class, this answer has nothing to do with anything that might help.